# boost locale c++ - understanding the basics

Tags: c++, boost, localization, locale

First of all How do i make the following example work (from boost website):

```
        #include <boost/locale.hpp>
        #include <iostream>

        using namespace std;
        using namespace boost::locale;

        int main()
        {
            generator gen;

            // Specify location of dictionaries
            gen.add_messages_path(".");
            gen.add_messages_domain("hello");

            // Generate locales and imbue them to iostream
            locale::global(gen(""));
            cout.imbue(locale());

            // Display a message using current system locale
            cout << translate("Hello World") << endl;
        }
```

(tried creating an hello.mo file but still didn't work).

Basically what i am trying to do is to be able to cout a string like: "operation",
and then according to file1 / file2 it will print the string value under id:operation for that specific file.

how can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[boost translate: po file not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238610/boost-translate-po-file-not-work) might help.

The most confusing step is:

> 2. Put the .mo file into the correct file structure, for example if your trying to translate to spanish this would be ./es_ES/LC_MESSAGES/hello.mo

It's a wraper of [GNU 'gettext' utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html). The manual is useful too.